# Does modifying a deleted answers bump a question?

Tags: bug, deleted-answers, bumping

Does modifying a deleted answers bump a question?

It just happened that [a deleted answer was edited](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1532535/revisions) by its poster and the question was bumped on the main site again:

[image]

Comment: Yes - as per [this MSE post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/42077/260340) this is by design.

Comment: A related feature request on [meta.se]: [Bump a deleted answer when it's undeleted, not when it's edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192918).