# Can I eliminate an answer after its deletion?

Tags: support, deletion, deleted-answers

I know that users with $10$k reputation can view other user's deleted answers. My question: Is there a way to completely delete an answer so that no one can view it?

Comment: I'd guess that for at least some of these early Answers, the concern you have for them suggests you'd be inclined to post a better solution now, if time permitted.  So consider improving some of those older Answers; your present insights may be useful to others, esp. if some tempting path turns out to be an insufficient attempt.

Comment: You can add a comment below your answer to disassociate yourself from it ("I was young and naive when I wrote this!"), and then delete it. Editing an answer, even a deleted answer, will bump the thread (this is by design - see the links [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21977/10513)), so comment rather than edit to disassociate yourself (thanks @quid for pointing this out to me).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, this is not possible. This will happen in only very severe cases (think links to child porn) and often those are [redacted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191121/295232) and not hard-deleted.

By posting content on Stack Exchange, you've agreed to the [Terms of Service](https://math.stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service#licensing) which state the following:

> #### Subscriber Content
>
> You agree that any and all content, including without limitation any and all text, graphics, logos, tools, photographs, images, illustrations, software or source code, audio and video, animations, and product feedback (collectively, “Content”) that you provide to the public Network (collectively, “Subscriber Content”), is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Overflow on a worldwide, royalty-free, non-exclusive basis pursuant to Creative Commons licensing terms (CC BY-SA 4.0)

Requesting permanent deletion would go against that. You do have the option to [request disassociation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96732/295232) by the same license, but if it's just a couple of posts only a handful of users can see (and *only* if they're actively looking for them), why bother?